# What are some chess songs?

Tags: history

What are some songs about chess?

Historical songs; pop songs; singalong songs, hymns, anthems; whatever you can find.

Comment: How is this question related to *Chess SE*? We deal with chess *positions* not with music. This question is off-topic in my opinion because it does not address a chess problem we can solve, but instead asks from us to do the "Google Search" for the OP. It is also too broad to be answered, especially since there are many answers that are equally good to be accepted as solution to the problem.

Comment: There's a whole musical of them (well not really, but there is a musical called _Chess_ about a chess tournament).

Comment: @sweeneyrod: In a sense, two musicals; the US and UK versions feature mostly the same songs, but the songs are in different sequence, many lyrics are altered, and the plot is largely different.

Comment: @supercat To the extent that one isn't about a chess tournament?!

Comment: @sweeneyrod: The UK version is about two chess tournaments: in the first, which takes place in Italy, the Russia champion falls in love with the American champion's second, defeats the American and then defects to the U.S.; in the second, which takes place in Bangkok, the former Russian plays against Russia's new champion, with the former American champion acting as commentator.  With his girlfriend's father being held hostage by the Soviets, he is pressured to throw the match but instead chooses to win and then return to Russia.

Comment: @sweeneyrod: The US version of the show only has one tournament, which takes place in Bangkok and is spread out over the two acts of the show.  As in the UK version the Russian falls in love with the American's second, but in the US version the American emerges victorious in the final showdown (rather than merely acting as commentator).

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Thank you for your criticism. While you are correct, that there is very little chess strategy being discussed, but I would say that the tag is appropriate that this is a chess history question that speaks to the popularity, aesthetic, and cultural influence of chess. I think you also make a fair point that the nature of this question makes it difficult to accept an answer. I thought about this, and decided if any definitive, traditional, or time immemorial chess song was discovered, that this would be appropriate to accept as an answer. What do you think?

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff  "We deal with chess positions not with music" Where is that specified? (I'm not arguing, just asking. it's just that I don't find anywhere what kind of questions are welcomed here - apart from being "about chess").

Comment: @leonbloy: Please read [this](http://chess.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) carefully and pay attention to following: *You should only ask **practical**, answerable questions **based on actual problems** that you face. **Chatty, open-ended** questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.* Emphasis are mine. Notice that this question already tends to be chatty, and is not related to **practical problem** OP faces.

Comment: @Akiva: Please read [this](http://chess.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) carefully and pay attention to following: *You should only ask **practical**, answerable questions **based on actual problems** that you face. **Chatty, open-ended** questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.* Emphasis are mine. Notice that this question already tends to be chatty, and is not related to **practical problem** you face.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff With that criteria (which still says nothing about "positions") about 90% of the questions currently on the top page should be considered as off topic.

Comment: @leonbloy: I agree, but I believe criteria has been loosened because site is in Beta stage and we **desperately** need questions. In my opinion, the quality of the site **has** already gone downhill :(

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Thank you for following up, and your thoughtful comment. Three issues: a) You did not respond to my post directed towards you, where I detailed a way to have this question practically answered. b) You did not address the fact that the tag to this question, "History" is relavent. As Leonbloy pointed out; "Positions" are not detailed in the criteria. c) You are the one who began the chat dialogue, and now you criticize this topic s being chatty. As to the practicality of this problem; this has been an enlightening topic about chess culture from my perspective.

Comment: @Akiva: *You are the one who began the chat dialogue* -> you have misunderstood me, I've meant about the nature of answers; *"Positions" are not detailed in the criteria* -> FAQ clearly states that `You should only ask **practical**, answerable questions based on **actual problems** that you face` ( emphasis are mine ); this question is very broad as I have said, and in your post you do not face any **practical** problem we can solve ( unless I am missing out something? ). I will address rest of your comment in another comment of mine since it can't fit here...

Comment: @Akiva: *You did not address the fact that the tag to this question, "History" is relavent.* -> As we can see from the FAQ, positions are the only **practical** problem you can have in chess. List of tags is only there to help OP better **describe** his/her **practical** problem; List of tags is **not** list of topics allowed. Just because we have a tag `endgame` doesn't mean someone can ask "How to play endgame?" ( too broad topic, OP didn't do research at all -> should be heavily downvoted and closed ). Tag **describes** a **practical** problem, which is a concrete chess position.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Thank you for following up. I see what you are saying; Unfortunately what you quoted says nothing about Chess Positions; That is something you think it implies. Actually; they speak of problems related to chess. *Problem* is a broad word. My *problem* here, is that I do not know any chess songs, or any song that is definitive towards chess. Ergo; it is practical for me to ask about Chess Songs. And if I do not ask about chess history or chess culture here, then answers to these questions will have to be painstakingly collected through google translate, informal forums.

Comment: @Akiva: That was the whole point of my comment that *this site is has already gone downhill* -> nobody stated **exact allowed topics**, nor we have a way that can clearly explain what is allowed or not, which some posts on Meta confirm. At the end, this discussion is about "does reader considers post on topic". I believe that we should leave decision of whether this is on topic or not to the community, as this already turns into "debate" which doesn't belong here. I would post a question on Meta but I feel it would be pointless... Let us agree that we respectfully disagree on this one...

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Thank you for sharing your thoughts and criticism. I will take up your offer to respectfully disagree, although I think you made some valid criticisms I agreed with. That being said, learning about chess culture, as a new player, has made me more interested in chess as a whole. The Ballad of Bobby Fischer for example introduced me to that individual, which I then watched a documentary on. Do you think Stack Exchanges should serve the purpose, or at least this one, to help get people more interested in the topic? Or do you prefer a cleaner more utilitarian format?

Comment: @Akiva: This is a good topic for Meta, we could continue discussion there... Best regards.

Comment: I remember Fritz used to sing this song - "I'm dreaming of the White...PIECES!!"

Answer (score 4):

One Night in Bangkok- Murray Head
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R9cNtrrCP0E&feature=kp

A cover of Adele's "Skyfall" with a chess-themed music video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oiXJQ0SG888

Comment: One Night in Bangkok is from a musical entitled `Chess`.

Answer (score 4):

[Vennaskond - Malemaja staar](http://youtu.be/1gvYik_1-pg) (translates to "Chess House star", I think) is an Estonian song from 1993 about GM Jaan Ehlvest. Too bad my Estonian is not very good, so I can't translate the lyrics. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are two parts of "Chess Crown's Honour" by Vladimir Vysotskii (in russian language).

1st one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TbJX8A1DZGk

Answer (score 2):

Andrei Rodionov & Boris Tikhomirov - Chess Computer (Synth-Pop)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0xflCP9aOo

Answer (score 2):

Yes ~ I've Seen All Good People: Your Move (1971)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1I4Q6Px_78

Answer (score 2):

checkmate, by Apathy immediately comes to mind

Comment: Could you share a link to make this song easily accessible?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gnejsdojw7w

Answer (score 2):

Dirty Work by Steely Dan contains what seems to be a chess reference.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ghcsrblhn7A&feature=kp

Answer (score 2):

"The Ballad of Bobby Fischer"

This song is played at the end of the Bobby Fischer Against The World 
Documentary

http://youtu.be/84TI3wnZqUg

Answer (score 2):

If you like rap:

dj muggs vs. gza the genius "Grandmasters" (it's a full-length album)

Comment: Could you share a link to make the album easily accessible?

Comment: Grand masters is a collaboration album between GZA and DJ Muggs. My favorite track on the album is "General Principles" (http://bit.ly/1ueOkJn) but the most obvious chess tracks are :- Queens Gambit(http://bit.ly/1Bop6fv)  and Advance Pawns(http://bit.ly/1EydHwn) but generally the whole album was about chess.

Answer (score 2):

"It's no sacrifice" - Elton John

Comment: How do you figure?